# Strange result in Mysql subtraction

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a simple table in my Mysql database.
The table *T* has a column *A*, of type tinyint unsigned, and lenght 1. I use that column to store some boolean values.

When I try to do some simple arithmetic stuff, I get very strange results, for example:
`SELECT A - 1 FROM T`
returns 0, correctly, if the value of A is 1, but returns 18446744073709551615 (I think ifs 2^64 - 1) if A is 0.

My question is... why, and how can I fix that?

EDIT: declaring A as Signed solves the problem... But I can't understand why. I get that probably if a column is unsigned, -1 is represented as a very large number (2^n - 1), but if the result is of the same type of the column you select, why a 64 bit number?

Comment: Declaring A as `INT SIGNED` might help

Comment: Yeah, you are right... but why the strange result?

Comment: Unsigned integers can't store negative values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsigned ints cannot hold a negative value

If you try and subtract 1 from 0 it loops back round to the largest value it can have

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signedness

Not sure if that makes much sense but let me know if still stuck and will try to explain better!

Comment: Now works but for me it's very strange... why a 1 bit unsigned number can't store -1 but can store a 64 bit positive number?

Comment: An unsigned number is unsigned as it cannot store a sign. It's a result of old computers where storage space was far more limited. If a 16-bit integer is signed then it can hold both positive and negative numbers in the range −32768 to 32767. If the same 16-bits is used to store an unsigned integer it can store between 0 and 65535 giving far larger representation. It's not strange; it's done on purpose for this very reason

Answer (score 1):

`Unsigned` means the variable cannot deal with negative numbers, even if it is involved as part of a calculation in SQL.
Try `signed`.